# SciChart - 3D series data point peaks change when rotating

Tags: scichart

When rotating various renderable series such `MountainRenderableSeries3D` and `WaterfallRenderableSeries3D`, the peaks of the data points change significantly as can be seen in the gif below. What causes this, and can anything be done to fix it? The Y values have a large range, from 0.000024 to 20.0. And the same set of data is inserted in to the data series multiple times along the Z axis, so the X and Y values are all the same. Changing the camera mode from Orthogonal to Perspective helps some, but not completely.

This is with SciChart 5.1.0.11405 and SharpDX 4.0.1.

**Orthogonal**
[image]

**Perspective**
[image]

Comment: I suspect your hardware is DirectX9 which has different rendering properties than DX11. There are several options in SciChart 3D to enable antialiasing or improve rendering quality. However, impossible to diagnose without more information. 

When reporting bugs: SciChart recommends to email bug-report. more details here! https://www.scichart.com/support-policy/